# Global Variables in functions with if statements

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, global, local

Okay, I am currently doing a project to make a blackjack game in python and I'm having some trouble.  One of my issues is I dont know when to define a variable as global, specifically in functions with if statements.  If I have a global variable outside the if statement, do I have to claim that the variable is global within the if statement as well? For example:

```
x = 5
def add():
    global x  <--- ?
    x += 1
    if x == 7:
        global x <--- ?
        x = 5
```

I'm pretty sure I need the "global x" at the 1st question mark, but what about at the second question mark? Would I still need to put a "global x" within my if statement if I wanted my if statement to update a global variable? Or does the global x at the beginning of the function make the x's inside the if statement global? Also, if I wanted to return x here, where should I do it?

Comment: Better try to avoid global variables and use them only when they are **really** necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Only one `global` statement is enough.

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-global_stmt):

> The `global` statement is a declaration which holds for the entire
>   current code block.

```
x = 5
def add():
    global x
    x += 1
    if x == 7:
        x = 5
```

> Also, if I wanted to return x here, where should I do it?

If you're using `global` in your function then the `return x` must come after the `global x` statement, if you didn't use any `global` statement and also didn't define any local variable `x` then you can `return x` anywhere in the function.

If you've defined a local variable `x` then `return x` must come after the definition.

Comment: Actually in almost all situations *no* global statement is enough ;-)